# c# - How can I filter the table based on a dropdown selection in mvc application and then display the data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am doing my first ever mvc application and I am kind of stuck. What I'm trying to do is filter the existing table based on the selection from the dropdown list. 
I have a Course table and a Teacher table and I'd like to be able to filter the Courses by who is teaching them.

This is my controller so far:

```
namespace TTimetable.Controllers
{
    public class CoursesController : Controller
    {
        private TimetabledbEntities db = new TimetabledbEntities();

        // GET: Courses
        public ActionResult Index(int teacher)
        {
            ViewBag.Teacher = new SelectList(db.Teacher, "teacher_Id", "lastName");
            var course = db.Course.Include(c => c.Classroom).Include(c => c.Teacher);
            return View(course.ToList());
        }
```

This is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TTimetable.Models.Course>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Courses";
}

<h2>Courses</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.course_start)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.course_end)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Classroom.classroom_no)
        </th>
        <th>
            teacher
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.course_start)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.course_end)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Classroom.classroom_no)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Teacher.firstName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<h2>Courses taught by:</h2>
@Html.DropDownList("Teacher", "Select teacher")
```

So far I was only able to make the dropdown list display the teachers from the database. Anyone who could help me with this? It'll be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do your `Details()`, `Create()` and `Edit()` methods have to do with the question - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And you dropdownlist needs to be inside a form that makes a GET call to the `Index()` method (or use ajax to return the filtered result)

Comment: Consider following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started and in particular this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search where the search pattern is explained

Comment: perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have your dropdown list post back to the server.  This can be accomplished by wrapping the dropdown in a form, and adding javascript to submit the form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Courses", FormMethod.Get))
{
    Html.DropDownList("Teacher", ViewBag.Teacher, "Select teacher", new { onchange = @"form.submit();" });
}
```

Comment: It says that HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<Course>>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax. ......... How can I cast it exactly? Sorry if Im asking stupid questions but I'm very new to this

Answer (score 0):

here viewbag should be casted as it is dynamic type object.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Teacher", (SelectList)ViewBag.Teacher, "Select teacher", new { onchange = @"form.submit();" });
```

hope it helps for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to use to Odata approach , when you have multiple filters , for a single table . It will be easy for you in the future.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/

combining both the techniques can help you.